# PowerBI visuals data alignment

Tags: sorting, date, charts, powerbi, axis-labels

The problem is about the misaligned data labels. I've got the table created with end of the months dates, but when I put thoes dates into chart with two axises the dates label are displayed under wrong points. [image: PowerBI chart with two axises] Why under "czerwiec date(June date)" the date for July (lip 2017) is displayed?

How to put all of the dates into right order